# Cassandra 2.1.3. How to extract CommitLog

Tags: java, maven, logging, cassandra, commit

Please help for my  problem. I use Ubuntu 14.04, Java 8, Cassandra 2.1.3. Sorry I'm beginner. How I can extract and deserialize commitLog from dir: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog? 
As far as I understand we may use lib for Maven cassandra-all, where is method CommitLogReplayer.recover? If I start recover commitLog, for example:

```
CommitLogReplayer.recover(new File("/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-4-1453270991708.log"));
```

I get exception:

```
Expecting URI in variable: [cassandra.config].  Please prefix the file with file:/// for local files or file://<server>/ for remote files. Aborting. If you are executing this from an external tool, it needs to set Config.setClientMode(true) to avoid loading configuration.
Fatal configuration error; unable to start. See log for stacktrace.
```

`Config.setClientMode(true);` - don't helped me.

What I am wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With setClientMode(true), there will be no context to deserialize the data unless you do something to create the cfmetadata yourself. Even then this is a pretty non trivial project since the applying of mutations is tightly coupled with C*. That said this isn't impossible, but you wont be able to use the CommitLogReplayer since it tries to apply the mutations. Its a good place to start looking to write your own though (up to CommitLogReplayer.replayMutation you can reuse a lot).

Comment: Thank you Chris! If I understand correctly standard methods of C* src dont't help me for solution this task? I need override or rewrite this methods by my solutions?

Comment: Correct, theres nothing built in to do this if your trying to examine contents of commitlog. If you want to just restore a commitlog, checkout https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configLogArchive_t.html. You can set the restore option and restart the node to replay them on a node.

Comment: Thanks for help Chris! I will think for another solution.